# Is the universe a thermodynamically isolated system?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, astrophysics

The concept of thermodynamic equilibrium is only valid for isolated systems. [Heat death of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe) can be understood as attainment of thermodynamic equilibrium.

There has been much fanfare about exploring heat death and what happens when we get there, but it isn't clear to me if we can even declare the universe an isolated system.

What evidence do we have which is consistent with the universe either being or not being an isolated system?

Is it even possible to ever surely declare that it is or isn't an isolated system?

Comment: It depends on whether or not the "universe" as we know it is all that there is out there. In which case, it is an isolated system. But we don't really know, do we?

Comment: I would like to comment regarding the question: "Is it even possible to ever surely declare that it is or isn't an isolated system?" It is a discipline of science (excluding mathematics) that that no hypothesis has a complete certainty of being correct, or of being incorrect.  However, in any particular science there is confidence threshold that if the likelihood that a hypothesis is true exceeds the threshold, then it is reasonable to    accept it as true (tentatively). If it  is less than the threshold, it isn't worth thinking about  it.

Comment: @Buzz so what is the threshold for the belief that the universe is an isolated system, and what are the observations which lead scientists to that belief? Are there previous attempts at falsification that failed, or does the belief hinge on answers to any open questions?

Comment: @Peeyush Kushwaha I am not qualified to describe this threshold. except as it applies to me personally.. There is no way to have any observable awareness of any reality involving something which is not in our isolated universe. The only use of thinking about sucn non-observable things is science fiction.

Comment: @Buzz I'll agree with you. Would you then say that discussion on heat death of the universe is also speculation / science fiction?

Comment: @Peeyush Kushwaha I would say, "NO!" Cosmologists have a model of  our universe that makes many observable predictions which have been verified by observation. The fact that some of the predictions relate to the future (and are therefore not currently observable) do not diminish the likelihood that the future predictions are correct.